# Remove /index from url nginx

Tags: html, nginx

I have a static website served using nginx. I have already removed the .html extension of every page (i.e /index.html becomes /index) using the code below

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        rewrite ^/([^\.]+)$ /$1.html break;
   }
```

When I visit the homepage `/` it redirects me to `/index`. I want to remove `/index` from the homepage so that whenever anyone visits `/` it doesn't redirect to `/index`

I have tried the following but none works.

```
location / {
        ...
        rewrite ^/index$ /permanent;
   }
```

```
location /index {
        rewrite ^/index(/.*)$ $1 last;
    }
```

Kindly assist.

Comment: Try: `location = / { try_files /index.html =404; }`